# Can't view db privileges in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb

Can't view db privileges
http://localhost:8080/server_privileges.php?db=XXXX&checkprivsdb=nb&viewing_mode=db

==> Error: #1267 - Illegal mix of collations

New installation
phpMyAdmin 5.0.4
Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.13
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation curl Documentation mbstring Documentation
PHP version: 7.4.13

[image: Character_sets]

```
( SELECT `User`, `Host`, `Select_priv`, `Insert_priv`, `Update_priv`, `Delete_priv`, `Create_priv`, `Drop_priv`, `Grant_priv`, `Index_priv`, `Alter_priv`, `References_priv`, `Create_tmp_table_priv`, `Lock_tables_priv`, `Create_view_priv`, `Show_view_priv`, `Create_routine_priv`, `Alter_routine_priv`, `Execute_priv`, `Event_priv`, `Trigger_priv`, '*' AS `Db`, 'g' AS `Type` FROM `mysql`.`user` WHERE NOT (`Select_priv` = 'N' AND `Insert_priv` = 'N' AND `Update_priv` = 'N' AND `Delete_priv` = 'N' AND `Create_priv` = 'N' AND `Drop_priv` = 'N' AND `Grant_priv` = 'N' AND `References_priv` = 'N' AND `Create_tmp_table_priv` = 'N' AND `Lock_tables_priv` = 'N' AND `Create_view_priv` = 'N' AND `Show_view_priv` = 'N' AND `Create_routine_priv` = 'N' AND `Alter_routine_priv` = 'N' AND `Execute_priv` = 'N' AND `Event_priv` = 'N' AND `Trigger_priv` = 'N')) UNION ( SELECT `User`, `Host`, `Select_priv`, `Insert_priv`, `Update_priv`, `Delete_priv`, `Create_priv`, `Drop_priv`, `Grant_priv`, `Index_priv`, `Alter_priv`, `References_priv`, `Create_tmp_table_priv`, `Lock_tables_priv`, `Create_view_priv`, `Show_view_priv`, `Create_routine_priv`, `Alter_routine_priv`, `Execute_priv`, `Event_priv`, `Trigger_priv`, `Db`, 'd' AS `Type` FROM `mysql`.`db` WHERE 'nb' LIKE `Db`     AND NOT (`Select_priv` = 'N' AND `Insert_priv` = 'N' AND `Update_priv` = 'N' AND `Delete_priv` = 'N' AND `Create_priv` = 'N' AND `Drop_priv` = 'N' AND `Grant_priv` = 'N' AND `References_priv` = 'N' AND `Create_tmp_table_priv` = 'N' AND `Lock_tables_priv` = 'N' AND `Create_view_priv` = 'N' AND `Show_view_priv` = 'N' AND `Create_routine_priv` = 'N' AND `Alter_routine_priv` = 'N' AND `Execute_priv` = 'N' AND `Event_priv` = 'N' AND `Trigger_priv` = 'N')) ORDER BY `User` ASC, `Host` ASC, `Db` ASC;
```

Error: #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '<>'

Answer (score 1):

set collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_general_ci'

[image]

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it